# How to validate multiple "if" statements in Python from a user's input

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task I need to do is the following;

- Create a Python file called full_name.py
- This program will be used to validate that **a user enters inputs at least two names** when asked to enter their full name.
- Ask the user to input their full name.
- Do some **validation to check that the user has entered a full name**. Give
  an appropriate error message if they haven’t. One of the following
  messages should be displayed based on the user’s input:

  - “You haven’t entered anything. Please enter your full name.”
  - “You have entered less than 4 characters. Please make sure that
    you have entered your name and surname.”
  - “You have entered more than 25 characters. Please make sure that
    you have only entered your full name.”
  - “Thank you for entering your name.”

This is the code that I have thus far;

```py
full_name = str(input("Please enter your full name below:\n"))

if (full_name.isalpha()):
    print ("You haven't entered anything. Please enter your full name")
```

I am not sure if this is 100% correct, but I am also not sure how to continue from here?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation of the function `isalpha`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

Comment: You must do 3 validations. Focus on one at a time!

Comment: 4, if you consider that the name must be formed of 2 parts.

Comment: A full name probably (almost definitely, aside from people with mononyms like Madonna) has a space in it. That's not alphabetic. Nor are hyphens or apostrophes, common in many last names.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the length of the input you could use the `len()` function, length of 0 means the user hasn't entered anything

for example for input under 4 characters:

```
    if len(full_name ) < 4:
        print("You have entered less than 4 characters")
```

Same but different parameters would be for the rest.

for checking if the name has two different parts, split by a whitespace.
you can split the name by whitespace and check if you have two parts.

```
parts = full_name.split(' ')
if len(parts) == 2:
    // name has two parts
```